# how to promote a module to global in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a library contained in a module that I use very often, so I want to promote it as "global" and use without requiring it.

In pure JavaScript it's easy as

```
window.mylib = require("mylib")
```

but I'm finding it difficult to do in TypeScript because apparently you can't mix "module" and "ambient" code. So this doesn't work:

```
import MyLib = require("mylib"); 
window.mylib = MyLib;  
interface Window {
    mylib: mylib;
}
```

because the Window interface is augmented only for one file.

Is there a way to do that (that doesn't include generating a custom  mylib.d.ts) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like:

yourModule.ts

```
import MyLib = require("mylib"); 

export {};

declare global {
    interface Window {
        mylib: mylib;
    }
}

window.mylib = MyLib;
```

And then you just import it when needed:

```
import "./yourModule";
```

It's shorty discussed in [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).